# Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 3 in SELECT statement in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have a table 'CustomerAccount' with the following fields:

1. AccountNumber
2. AmountDue
3. CompanyName
4. Cust_FirstName
5. Cust_LastName
6. Address

I am trying to pull a simple report but I get an error message. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

**My Code:**

```
SELECT AccountNumber
      ,AmountDue
      --,ISNULL(Cust_LastName, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Cust_FirstName, '') CustomerName
      ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(CompanyName, '') = '' 
            THEN Cust_LastName + ', ' + Cust_FirstName
            ELSE CompanyName
       END CustomerName
       -- Above: This is the line where it gives an error.  
       -- If there is no Company Name then give the Last and First name of the customer.


      ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(CompanyName, '') = '' 
            THEN ''
            ELSE Cust_FirstName + ' ' + Cust_LastName
       END Attn_To
      -- Above: If there IS a Company Name then give the First and Last name of the customer.

      ,[Address]

FROM CustomerAccount
```

The Error Message:

> *Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 3 in SELECT statement.*

**What I have tried:**

```
  ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(CompanyName, '') = '' 
        THEN ''  --Cust_LastName + ', ' + Cust_FirstName
        ELSE CompanyName
   END CustomerName
 -- This works but only gives a CompanyName when there is one.
 -- But does not give me the customer name when there is no CompanyName
```

If I try only `,ISNULL(Cust_LastName, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Cust_FirstName, '')` instead of the CASE Statement then it works. I get the LastName, FirstName of the customer.

Comment: What are the column data types?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15095183/6327676

Comment: Looks like a common question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1607560/2109512

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it:

```
  ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(CompanyName, '') = '' 
        THEN Cust_LastName + ', ' + Cust_FirstName
        ELSE CompanyName
   END COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI CustomerName
```

Thanks to @Aaron Bertrand , @Paul and @DT.